# Exercise on Levy measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, borel-measures, levy-processes

I have to prove that a Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$ such that
$$
\int_0^\infty (z\wedge z^2)\mu(dz)<\infty
$$
is a Levy measure.

MY ATTEMPT:

We need to check that $\int_0^\infty(1\wedge z^2)\mu(dz)<\infty$; in particular we have:
$$
\begin{split}
\int_0^\infty(1\wedge z^2)\mu(dz) & =\int_0^1(1\wedge z^2)\mu(dz)+\int_1^\infty(1\wedge z^2)\mu(dz)\\
& \leq \int_0^1\mu(dz)+\int_1^\infty(z\wedge z^2)\mu(dz)\\
& =\mu([0,1))+\int_1^\infty(z\wedge z^2)\mu(dz)<\infty
\end{split}
$$
Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is not quite correct as Lévy measures may be infinite on $(0,1]$.

Notice that for $x>0$
$$1\wedge x^2 \leq \big(x\wedge x^2\big)\mathbb{1}_{(0,1]}(x) + \big(x\wedge x^2\big)\mathbb{1}_{(1,\infty)}(x)=x\wedge x^2 $$